# Error mounting USB drive on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, usb, mount, hard-drive

I have a USB drive that I used to mount on my Ubuntu 14.04 config (it was working perfectly).

Now I get the following message each time I connect it to a USB port :

```
Error mounting /dev/sdk1 at /media/laurent06000/Large: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sdk1" "/media/laurent06000/Large"' exited with non-zero exit status 13: $MFTMirr does not match $MFT (record 0).
Failed to mount '/dev/sdk1': Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.
```

[image: Error Message]

I could find a post related to this in the ubuntu forum :

[[SOLVED] Ubuntu 14.04 - Seagate external hard drive does not mount](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2240581)

but the solution - provided in [Edit 3] (making a chkdsk [drive:] /f) that I performed on this disk DOES NOT show any error and DOES NOT solve my problem.

I tried on different USB ports without any change.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Laurent

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution to my problem.

At address [How to fix ‘$MFTMirr does not match $MFT (record 0)’](https://wmarkito.wordpress.com/2010/12/29/how-to-fix-mftmirr-does-not-match-mft-record-0/)

I followed the instruction :

sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdk1

which gave me the following result :

```
Attempting to correct errors...
Processing $MFT and $MFTMirr...
Reading $MFT... OK
Reading $MFTMirr... OK
Comparing $MFTMirr to $MFT... FAILED
Correcting differences in $MFTMirr record 0...OK
Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.
Setting required flags on partition... OK
Going to empty the journal ($LogFile)... OK
```

But stopped after this line and seemed to start an infinite loop.

I then closed the terminal which told me that a process was running.

When I tried to mount the USB drive it told me that the ressource was busy (certainly because of the still running process)

I then disconnected and reconnected the USB drive physically but failed again with the message :

```
Error mounting /dev/sdk1 at /media/laurent06000/Large: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sdk1" "/media/laurent06000/Large"' exited with non-zero exit status 13: $MFTMirr does not match $MFT (record 0).
Failed to mount '/dev/sdk1': Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.
```

I then came back to my Windows 8.1 PC and re-issue a "chkdsk [drive:] /f" command.

That time chkdsk managed to correct the problem by saying :

```
Correcting errors in the master file table (MFT) mirror.
Correcting errors in the Volume Bitmap.
```

Now the USB drive automount itself properly.

Hope this can be of any help.

Laurent

Comment: I would have never thought to run chkdsk against drive in Windows. My first thought was a mistake in fstab. Learn something new everyday. Also I think you could have done this in Ubuntu with **fsck /dev/sdk1**

Comment: I didn't try it with fsck /dev/sdk1

Answer (score 0):

I Can't help with Ubuntu. But that pen drive properly mounted in windows
first it will ask for the scan and fix for the removable drive:

[image: windows pops up when USB inserted]

choose `scan and fix` and then choose `start` as showed below:

[image: after choosing scan and fix this windows will pop up]

It will take some time.
After completing that operation, insert the USB back to Ubuntu. It worked

Comment: You could try to revise(edit) your post and format it a bit better, see [here](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) how.